# How do I calculate the offsets for pagination?

Tags: php, pagination

I am working on a pagination feature in a web service I am writing, but my lack of math insight is killing me now.
I have a couple of keys: `totalItems`, `currentItems`, `currentPage`, `totalPages`, but also a couple of links to `first`, `last`, `previous` and `next`.

At this moment, I am doing the following calculations:

- `totalItems`: number of rows in the table
- `currentItems`: `limit` parameter from HTTP request
- `currentPage`: `start` parameter divided by `limit` parameter
- `totalPages`: number of rows in the table divided by `limit`. (Rounded up, 8.1 page = 9 pages)

I assume those calculations to be correct, what I **am** struggling with is the following:

- `first`: `start` parameter is 1 with `limit` from the HTTP request
- `last`: should be the first item of the last page, how do I calculate this correctly?
- `previous`: should be the first item of the previous page, how do I do this?
- `next`: should be the first item of the next page, how do I do this?

What I would like to ask, is: are my calculations correct? And how do I tackle the three problems with `last`, `previous` and `next`?

Comment: How do u control the paging? U pass the offset in the querystring or the page number?

Comment: The query string in HTTP looks like this: api?start=x&limit=y
So start if the offset of the number of items, and limit is number of items per page.

Comment: Then see answer, but it is easier to just work with api?page=X though

Comment: @DarkBee I agree it's easier, unfortunately, I can't use it for this project.

Comment: @DarkBee The question has nothing to do with the query string. It is about calculating offsets.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you work with mysql its

```
LIMIT offset, items_per_page
```

To calculate the offset u can use

```
$offset = ($page - 1) * $items_per_page;
```

Then replace the `$page` accordingly.

Last

```
$last_offset = ($totalPages - 1) * $items_per_page;
```

Previous

```
$previous_offset = (($currentPage - 1) - 1) * $items_per_page;
```

Next

```
$next_offset = (($currentPage + 1) - 1) * $items_per_page;
```

EDIT :

```
if ($previous_offset > 0) echo '<a href="?start='.$previous_offset.'&limit='.$items_per_page.'>prev</a>';


if ($next_offset <= $totalPages * $items_per_page) echo '<a href="?start='.$next_offset.'&limit='.$items_per_page.'">prev</a>';
```

Comment: So, if I am correct, I create a HTTP link to last page like this:
api?start=($totalPages-1)*limit&limit=limit?

Am I thinking righteously?

Comment: Yes if you use start and limit in the querystring :)

Comment: I'll be testing this right away, I'll post an update whether I succeeded or not!

Comment: With `start` = 1 and `limit` = 2, I'm getting negative offsets, that doesn't sound right?

Comment: U'll need to check wether u need to show the previous and next links though indeed.

Comment: I haven't got a clue what the check would look like, though, is there a simple algorithm for?

Comment: How do you calculate totalPages here @DarkBee

Comment: `totalPages` is defined by OP as "number of rows in the table divided by limit. (Rounded up, 8.1 page = 9 pages)"

Comment: Did you create this answer with ChatGPT?

Answer (score 4):

If for **limit** you are referring to the count of items per page, then:

```
currentItems: same as limit
currentPage: floor(start / limit)
totalPages: ceil(totalItems / limit)
last: totalPages * limit
previous: (currentPage-1) * limit // Should be greater or equal to 0
next: (currentPage+1) * limit // Should be less or equal than totalPages
```

It's just an approximation...

Comment: How to calculate this with start as 0

Answer (score 4):

I have gone through lots of articles and create very simple formula for pagination

```
offset = (limit * page no) - limit
```

For example, if the limit is 5

```
LIMIT 5
    page 1 
        offset : no (No need to use offset)
        (5 - 1) - 5
         select * from users limit 5

    page 2
        offset : 5
        (5 * 2) - 5
        select * from users limit 5 offset 5

    page 3 
        offset 10
        (5 * 3) - 5
        select * from users limit 5 offset 10

    page 4 
        offset 15
        (5 * 4) - 5
        select * from users limit 5 offset 15
```

select * from table name limit 5 offset value (calculated from the formula)

this is worked for me

Comment: it's `(5 * 1) - 5` instead of `(5 - 1) - 5` right?

Comment: We don't need offset, when we are looking for page 1 records, Simply limit is enough

Answer (score -1):

For here I'm used code below and works fine.

```
<?php
//curpage = current page;
//-1 = for adjust actual page;
//30 = total post for each page;
//5 = jump or offset determided for start count post 
?>

<?php $offset = (($curpage - 1) * 30) + 5 ;?>
<!-- print for view test -->
<h1><?php echo $offset ?></h1>
<?php
    $args_2 = array(
      'offset' => $offset,
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'posts_per_page' => 30,
      'category_name'     => $cat_filter,
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'paged' => $paged
    );

  $query = new WP_Query( $args_2 );

  if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
      ?>
```