# Dealing with value based pagination given a number of a page

Tags: sql, postgresql, algorithm, pagination

When using **value based** pagination

```
select * from articles 
where id > @start_value 
limit @page_size
```

how can I calculate `@start_value` **given only page number**?

Namely: say, I had a website and html page with a list of articles that I needed to paginate. But even to render the very 1st page, I'd need to calculate `@start_value` somehow. The input from a user would be a number of a page which he clicked; for the very first page it'd be 1 - by default.

- given that 1, how would I calcualate `@start_value`?
- or given any random page, still how would I calcualate `@start_value`?

Note that the values of the column `id` of a table aren't necessarily sequential, even if `id` is autoincremented.

Comment: You need an ordering for pagination, because the order of rows in a table is not well defined.

Answer (score 0):

First off, pagination without any sorting is not ideal. You can't guarantee how SQL will sort your results without including and `order by` clause.

You will also need to know the page size to calculate your start value, but given `@page_num`, and `@page_size`: `@start_value` is calculated by `@start_value = @page_num * @page_size;`.

Here it is without the `where` clause and with `limit`/`offset` instead

```
    select * 
    from articles
    order by id
    limit @page_size
    offset (@page_size * @page_num)
```

Comment: Re-read my answer. You need the page_size in order to calculate the start_value. Your question even includes the `@pagesize` variable in the query. Does it deserve a downvote because I specified that this is the case? Good luck finding an answer, mate.

Comment: Maybe these will help: [Pagination #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520996/calculating-item-offset-for-pagination) [Pagination #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27992413/how-do-i-calculate-the-offsets-for-pagination/27992616) [Math behind pagination](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68285/calculating-number-of-items-displayed-pagination)

Comment: Know the answer -- post it. I don't need the links.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the "where id > ..." part. The right way of achieving this is using `limit @page_size offset @offset` construct. This way you don't have to worry about the gaps. To calculate the offset based on page number, you just have to multiply page_size * page_number. Another important thing is that you should order your registers if you want to have the same result always. If you don't trust the IDs, you can order by date or another field. So:

```sql
select * from articles
order by date
limit @page_size
offset (@page_size * (@page_num-1))
```

Note: I used (@page_num-1) to start with a 0 offset for page 1.

Comment: Hey, why downvoting. What you asked is not possible because of the gaps that you can have in IDs as you pointed out. Thats why the right way of doing pagination is using an offset in the number of records instead of doing it in the IDs, as I or @NickDolan stated.

Comment: Or rather only you know about is offset based pagination.

Comment: What you are asking for, is also an offset based pagination (what is @start_value but an offset?). The problem is that you want to apply that offset to the primary key (ID) instead of the number of records. Not saying it's impossible, but it won't paginate correctly because of the possible gaps. But if you prefer using ID, go on, you can calculate the first value using the min() function. Regards!

Comment: No, that's not it.